# Magento 2: Css changes not reflecting

Tags: error, css, magento2.2

I am using Magento 2.2.1. I want to do changes in my CSS file. After inspecting on the website I am finding the source of CSS is from somewhere in pub/static folder. I tried editing the CSS in that folder and after that I ran the deploy command. But again my CSS is reverting back to the older one. Kindly help anyone. I have tried all the solutions provided in this website but am unable to get a correct way out of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not edit/modify files within pub/* or vendor/* directory.

The pub folder is for deployment only. Magento uses LESS CSS preprocessing for managing styles of themes and works in the following manner:

[image: Magento CSS Preprocessing]

Instead of making changes in pub folder's css or js files or working directly in vendor folder, follow these steps:

- create a new theme inside app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{yourTheme}/. If you are already using some theme then skip this step.
- edit .less within your theme so the changes stay visible and don't get replaced when clearing the cache or upgrading the system.
- Use grunt to compile your .less into deployment files.

For more info, have a look at the following useful links:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html
- http://inchoo.net/magento-2/working-with-css-in-your-first-magento-2-project/

Comment: Sir,
I added my css the app folder as suggested by you, but still when I am doing any changes in that file my css is not getting changed. I have cleared the cache and even runned the deploy command.

Comment: one more question. do i need to create .less file or .css file will do?? because i have created .css file.

Comment: Are you able to see the changes now? As you have said that your query is resolved now.

Comment: yes. but i am editing in a different file but using !important in every css.

Comment: There is no need to use !important. Just follow the standards of LESS in Magento 2.

Comment: but without !important those css are not overridding.

Comment: i m elaborating..actually all the css those are written in my pub/static folder and the name of css is config_1.css. But i dont have any config_1.css/ config_1.less file in my app/design/frontend/.. folder. Instead I have a file named as style.less. In this file whenever I write any css with !important I seen the changes are reflected on my website. Hence i have started coding in style.less. Is there any way i can edit in config_1 file, so that i dont have to use !important in every style i define.

Comment: anyone kindly reply