# How to have the changes made in .less file be reflected on the website?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, less-css, magento2.2.6, less-compilation

I'm trying to make some style changes to a .less file in a custom module. But even after making and saving the changes to the .less file, those changes are not being reflected on the website. I'm using Magento in developer mode.
Is there a way around this(by using cli) which does not involve deleting pub or generated folders?

Comment: did you try using cache:clean command?

Comment: I did. I also have all the cache disabled, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reference link from where you can take help on it--

1) https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

2) [How can I compile less file in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82801/how-can-i-compile-less-file-in-magento2)

3) [Magento 2: Css changes not reflecting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207357/magento-2-css-changes-not-reflecting)

4) [Clear Theme/CSS Cache in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82166/clear-theme-css-cache-in-magento-2)

still having issue, please comment.